# foreign key referencing multiple tables - using multiple FKs

Tags: mysql

I have child table, A, which needs to refer to either of two different tables, B and C. B and C are similar but need to be in different tables.

As I understand it, mysql only allows a FK to refer to one table. Therefore, and having looked at other solutions, I've decided to create two columns in A to refer to either B or C. As it should only be B or C i've added in a constraint to prevent them both being NOT NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE conversions
(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
kicker_id INT NOT NULL,
success BOOL NOT NULL,
try_id INT,
penalty_try_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (try_id),
FOREIGN KEY (penalty_try_id),

CONSTRAINT conversions_coll_null CHECK (try_id IS NULL OR penalty_try_id IS NULL)
);
```

Will this work? Is it a good design?

Thanks

Comment: you're missing the foreign key definitions

Comment: My MySQL isn't very good but would it be better to say: `CONSTRAINT conversions_coll_null CHECK (try_id IS NULL <> penalty_try_id IS NULL)` That way it'll enforce one of the ids not being NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fine approach (assuming you add in the foreign key definitions), but with an important caveat:  MySQL does not actually enforce `check` constraints.  So, although you can include the constraint in the definition, it doesn't do anything.

If you want to insist on the constraint, then you need to use a trigger.

By the way, if you want to ensure that exactly one of the columns has a value, use `XOR` rather than `OR`.  This would be expressed as:

```
CHECK (try_id IS NULL XOR penalty_try_id IS NULL)
```

(Or course, this doesn't do anything in MySQL, but it is just to show the correct logic.)